# Keras Concatenated Model Doesn't learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

i'm trying to build a model that can predict emotions using  7 models concatenated .
Each of the 7 model represents a part of the face: mouth, left_eye, right_eye...ect

the problem is the model doesn't learn at all: from the 2nd epoch to the last one 100 : i have 15% accuracy, no changes in acuracy or loss during all the epochs.

i think maybe the problem is in my model cocatenated or my fit function ( the train and labels data)

there is 7 Emotions : sad, angry , happy ....ect

Here is my model and my compile and train and my datasets
**Model**

```
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input, concatenate
from keras.models import Sequential, Model
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Flatten



def build_all_faceparts_model(input_shape,batch_shape,num_classes):
  input1=Input(input_shape)
  input2=Input(input_shape)
  input3=Input(input_shape)
  input4=Input(input_shape)
  input5=Input(input_shape)
  input6=Input(input_shape)
  input7=Input(input_shape)

  # Create the model for right eye
  right_eye=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input1,  batch_input_shape = batch_shape) (input1)
  right_eye=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(right_eye)
  right_eye=Dropout(0.25)(right_eye)
  right_eye=Flatten()(right_eye)


  # Create the model for leftt eye
  left_eye=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input2,  batch_input_shape = batch_shape) (input2)
  left_eye=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(left_eye)
  left_eye=Dropout(0.25)(left_eye)
  left_eye=Flatten()(left_eye)

  # Create the model for right eyebrow
  right_eyebrow=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input3,  batch_input_shape = batch_shape) (input3)
  right_eyebrow=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(right_eyebrow)
  right_eyebrow=Dropout(0.25)(right_eyebrow)
  right_eyebrow=Flatten()(right_eyebrow)


  # Create the model for leftt eye
  left_eyebrow=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input4,  batch_input_shape = batch_shape) (input4)
  left_eyebrow=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(left_eyebrow)
  left_eyebrow=Dropout(0.25)(left_eyebrow)
  left_eyebrow=Flatten()(left_eyebrow)



  # Create the model for mouth
  mouth=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input5,  batch_input_shape = batch_shape) (input5)
  mouth=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(mouth)
  mouth=Dropout(0.25)(mouth)
  mouth=Flatten()(mouth)

  # Create the model for nose
  nose=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input6,  batch_input_shape = batch_shape) (input6)
  nose=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(nose)
  nose=Dropout(0.25)(nose)
  nose=Flatten()(nose)



  # Create the model for jaw
  jaw=Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input7,  batch_input_shape = batch_shape) (input7)
  jaw=MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(jaw)
  jaw=Dropout(0.25)(jaw)
  jaw=Flatten()(jaw)



  concatenated = concatenate([right_eye, left_eye, right_eyebrow, left_eyebrow, mouth, nose, jaw],axis = -1)
  out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(concatenated)
  model = Model([input1,input2,input3,input4,input5,input6,input7], out)


  return model
```

**train and test datasets** Here X_train_all is a list of datasets, not like y_train_all

```
X_train_all=[X_train_mouth,X_train_right_eyebrow,X_train_left_eyebrow,X_train_right_eye,X_train_left_eye,X_train_nose,X_train_jaw]


X_test_all=[X_test_mouth,X_test_right_eyebrow,X_test_left_eyebrow,X_test_right_eye,X_test_left_eye,X_test_nose,X_test_jaw]

y_train_all=y_train_mouth+y_train_right_eyebrow+y_train_left_eyebrow+y_train_right_eye+y_train_left_eye+y_train_nose+y_train_jaw

y_test_all=y_test_mouth+y_test_right_eyebrow+y_test_left_eyebrow+y_test_right_eye+y_test_left_eye+y_test_nose+y_test_jaw
```

**compile**

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam
input_shape =X_train_mouth[0].shape
batch_shape = X_train_mouth[0].shape


model_all_faceparts=build_all_faceparts_model(input_shape,batch_shape,7)

#Compile Model
model_all_faceparts.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(lr=1e-3),metrics=["accuracy"])


lr_reducer = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.9, patience=3)
early_stopper = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', min_delta=0, patience=15, mode='auto')
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(current_dir+'/weights_jaffe.hd5', monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
```

**Train**

```
history=model_all_faceparts.fit(
          X_train_all, y_train_all, batch_size=7, epochs=100, verbose=1,callbacks=[lr_reducer, checkpointer, early_stopper])
```

**output**

```
    Epoch 1/100
181/181 [==============================] - 19s 107ms/step - loss: 94.6603 - acc: 0.1271
Epoch 2/100
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py:1109: RuntimeWarning: Reduce LR on plateau conditioned on metric `val_loss` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,acc,lr
  (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py:434: RuntimeWarning: Can save best model only with val_loss available, skipping.
  'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/callbacks.py:569: RuntimeWarning: Early stopping conditioned on metric `val_acc` which is not available. Available metrics are: loss,acc,lr
  (self.monitor, ','.join(list(logs.keys()))), RuntimeWarning
181/181 [==============================] - 15s 81ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 3/100
181/181 [==============================] - 15s 81ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 4/100
181/181 [==============================] - 15s 83ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 5/100
181/181 [==============================] - 15s 84ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 6/100
181/181 [==============================] - 15s 85ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 7/100
181/181 [==============================] - 16s 86ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 8/100
181/181 [==============================] - 16s 87ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 9/100
181/181 [==============================] - 16s 86ms/step - loss: 95.9962 - acc: 0.1492
Epoch 10/100
```

Comment: I think the line `out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(concatenated)` has to be `out = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')(out)`

Comment: Have you normalized your data ? Between 0 and 1 for example ? This seems more a data problem than a coding issue. Providing the console output of the `fit` part would help

Comment: yes data normalized , and i did the to_categorical to y 

okey, wait i'm gonna add the output

Comment: i did put the true model, because the previous one my friend added some layers to try, check the model again please

Comment: maybe the problem is in the y_train? because my model tries to predict emotions from 7 classes, and my y is to_categorical, and it's not like the X_train

Comment: @DetchKing: Can you please let us know if your issue is resolved. Is it the problem with `y_train`? If possible, can you please specify the answer so that it would help the community. Thanks!

Comment: the problem was in the model itself, i just changed the model (added some layers) and everything was fine concluding to 93% accuracy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I completly forgot this post)
The problem was in the model itself, i just changed the model (added some layers) and everything was fine concluding to 93% accuracy!

PS: thanks to the tensorflow support guy that did remind me to post an answer